# Update Movesense firmware Dfu

Tags: android, movesense

I'm trying to update the firmware on the sensor with the latest release as it's currently with the original firmware it came with when it was delivered.

If I open the Android app and enter run Dfu mode, the status is Error and if I press Enable DFU I get this error through the console

```
07-29 17:49:52.137 2417-2516/com.movesense.mds.sampleapp E/Komposti: [SDS 
RESPONSE] type: PUT status: NOT_FOUND header: {"Status": 404, "TaskId": 22, 
"Reason": "NOT_FOUND", "Uri": "suunto://ECKI2FC78291/System/Mode", "Content-
Length": 0}
```

And the nrf toolbox dfu don't show the sensor to select it.

So my question is, how can I update the sensor if it's not possible through the app to start working in it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With old firmware you have to use "/Device/System/Mode" instead of "/System/Mode". In bitbucket there is iOS branch with "Support for older system mode path when setting to fw update mode"

Comment: Thanks I'm using the android version, so I'll try to change that bit or just checkout to a previous commit to see if I can update it.